# Wildfly redirect HTTP to HTTPS without port number in URL

Tags: https, port, wildfly

I have installed bitnami wildfly 10 in windows server 2012 R2. How to redirect wildfly from http to https without including port 8443 in URL? When i use `proxy-address-forwarding=true` in HTTP listener, still the port number appears in URL.

Comment: Port 8443 isn't the standard HTTPS port (443 is) so you must have it in the URL.

Comment: I suggest that you use reverse proxy that will redirect all traffic from `https://yourhost/` to `https://yourhost:8443` or `http://yourhost:8080` (to save some CPU power).

You can set up reverse proxy using your IIS: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis